# eliminar datos CSV con java

Tags: php, java, csv

Tengo un problema con un CSV descargado con php, este se me ha descargado y contiene en su interior a parte de la información que necesito, la información de las cabeceras http y necesito eliminar eso, para poder limpiar el CSV para una automatización posterior.

He creado una función en java la cual me lee el contenido del CSV perfectamente. Ahora necesito eliminar el contenido que no necesito y guardar ese CSV de nuevo...

mi código actual es el siguiente

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, CsvValidationException {
    String archCSV = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\MYLAR.csv";
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(archCSV));
    String[] fila = null;
    while((fila = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
        System.out.println(fila[0]);
    }

    csvReader.close();
}
```

la salida es la siguiente

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2g PHP/5.6.19 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Vary: Host
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.19
Pragma: public
Last-Modified: Wed
Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: pre-check=0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Transfer-Encoding: none
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tarifa_general.csv
Content-Length: 1682234
Set-Cookie:
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8

CATEGORY_PATH;MANUFACTURER;ID_PRODUCT;PRODUCT;REFERENCE;REFERENCE_PARENT;STOCK;EAN13;SHORT_DESCRIPTION;PRICE_CUSTOMER
PERIFÉRICOS > IMPRESORAS / FAX > IMPRESORAS > EPSON > MATRICIALES";EPSON;1;"IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-2190";C11CA92001;;0;8715946459172;000003;910.33
```

Como se puede observar está todo el contenido de las cabeceras HTTP. El CSV es mucho más largo, pero solo he puesto un ejemplo.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano

**Actualización:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
                                          IOException,
                                          CsvValidationException,
                                          CsvException {
Path archCSV = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "MYLAR.csv");
CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').build();
File file = new File("MYLAR2.CSV");
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(archCSV, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(br).withCSVParser(parser).build();
     FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(file);
     CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile)) {

    // adding header to csv
    String[] header = {"Fabricante", "ID_PRODUCT", "PRODUCTO", "REFERENCIA", "STOCK", "EAN13", "PRECIO"};
    writer.writeNext(header);

    String col1 = "";
    String col2 = "";
    String col3 = "";
    String col4 = "";
    String col5 = "";
    String col6 = "";
    String col7 = "";
    String col8 = "";

    // Skip HTTP Headers
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;)
        if (line.isEmpty())
            break; // Found end of HTTP Headers

    String[] fila = null;
    while ((fila = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        col1 = fila[0]; // path
        col2 = fila[1]; // fabricante
        col3 = fila[2]; // ID_PRODUCT
        col4 = fila[3]; // producto
        col5 = fila[4]; // referencia
        col6 = fila[6]; // stock
        col7 = fila[7]; // EAN13
        col8 = fila[9]; // PRECIO

        try {
            String[] data1 = new String[fila.length];
            // add data to csv
            for (int i = 1; i < fila.length; i++) {
                data1[i] = fila[i];
            }
            writer.writeNext(data1);

            // closing writer connection
            writer.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // code here
    }
}

}
```

Este fragmento de código, me genera esta salida la cual no es válida para mi:

```
    Fabricante,"ID_PRODUCT","PRODUCTO","REFERENCIA","STOCK","EAN13","PRECIO"
,"MANUFACTURER","ID_PRODUCT","PRODUCT","REFERENCE","REFERENCE_PARENT","STOCK","EAN13","SHORT_DESCRIPTION","PRICE_CUSTOMER"
,"EPSON","1","IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-2190","C11CA92001","","0","8715946459172","000003","910.33"
,"EPSON","3","IMPRESORA EPSON LX-1170 II","C11C641001","","0","8715946316963","000008","428.91"
,"EPSON","4","IMPRESORA EPSON FX-890 II","C11C524025","","0","8715946333137","000012","595.29"
,"EPSON","5","IMPRESORA EPSON FX-2190","C11C526022","","0","8715946204420","000013","714.87"
,"EPSON","6","IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-680 PRO","C11C376125","","0","8715946333205","000021","664.98"
,"EPSON","8","IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-630","C11C480019","","0","8715946538068","000025","498.67"
,"EPSON","11","IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-690","C11CA13041","","0","8715946429939","000091","583.8"
,"EPSON","12","IMPRESORA EPSON LX-350","C11CC24031","","0","8715946502939","000092","171.23"
,"EPSON","17","SCANNER EPSON WORKFORCE DS-7500N","B11B205331BT","","0","8715946510705","000157","1063.95"
,"EPSON","18","TRACTOR PUSH/PULL ( FX-2190 )  C12C800212*","C12C800212","","0","0","000230","59.54"
,"EPSON","19","IMPRESORA EPSON TMU-950 PARALELO BLANCA","C31C176252LG","","0","8715946367842","000248","512.8"
,"EPSON","21","IMPRESORA EPSON ACULASER COLOR C2800N","C11CA09001BZ","","0","8715946403878","000251","294.51"
,"EPSON","22","IMPRESORA EPSON EPL-6200N","C11C533011BR","","0","9314020599675","000254","168.41"
,"EPSON","24","SCANNER EPSON PERFECTION V500 OFFICE ADF","B11B189081","","0","8715946448664","000257","194.32"
```

Un antiguo desarrollador, creó un script en MDB, que recogía los CSV de los proveedores, los transformaba y este es el resultado que se obtiene con ese script:

```
C11CA92001  910.33  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-2190
C11C641001  428.91  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON LX-1170 II
C11C524025  595.29  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON FX-890 II
C11C526022  714.87  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON FX-2190
C11C376125  664.98  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-680 PRO
C11C480019  498.67  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-630
C11CA13041  583.8   0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-690
C11CC24031  171.23  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON LX-350
B11B205331BT    1063.95 0   MYLAR   SCANNER EPSON WORKFORCE DS-7500N
C12C800212  59.54   0   MYLAR   TRACTOR PUSH/PULL ( FX-2190 )  C12C800212*
C31C176252LG    512.8   0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON TMU-950 PARALELO BLANCA
C11CA09001BZ    294.51  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON ACULASER COLOR C2800N
C11C533011BR    168.41  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON EPL-6200N
B11B189081  194.32  0   MYLAR   SCANNER EPSON PERFECTION V500 OFFICE ADF
C11CB61011  0   0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON ACULASER M 7000N
B11B209301BT    381.92  0   MYLAR   SCANNER EPSON GT-S55
C11CC25001  188.01  0   MYLAR   IMPRESORA EPSON LQ-350
32GB    3.29    0   MYLAR   PENDRIVE KINGSTON 32GB  USB 2.0
INFD64GBPASBLS  PEN64GB 7.34    0   MYLAR   PENDRIVE INTEGRAL 64GB* USB 2.0
```

Así necesito generar yo un CSV con java, porqué¿?? porque, actualmente, actualizamos una base de datos, con los articulos, stock, unidades, etc de cada distribuidor que tenemos, pero hay que hacerlo manualmente. Es decir, hay que entrar a las webs de los distribuidores, descargar las tarifas y usar el script mdb que comenté anteriormente para transformar esos archivos en lo que he adjuntado anteriormente. Pero yo he conseguido con CURL en PHP, obtener de manera automática los CSV de los distribuidores y ahora quiero automatizar el proceso al 100%. Osea, descargar con PHP los archivos y con java, generar el nuevo CSV y actualizar la base de datos.

Actualmente tenemos también un pequeño inconveniente, que por eso se ha pensando en cambiar la forma de trabajar y es que, cuando el script MDB, transforma los CSV, hay que abrirlos y volverlos a guardar, porque no ha generado bien el fichero o desconocemos las razones. Por lo tanto, necesito generar un CSV bien hecho para que luego con java pueda actualizar la base de datos. Espero que ahora esté todo bien explicado

Comment: Los headers vienen originalmente en el archivo CSV ?

Comment: si, en este al menos, si. Este CSV es descargado con PHP directamente y al abrirlo por primera vez me encontre esto

Comment: Cuál es el contenido que no necesitas? Podrías comenzar por probar guardar el mismo contenido que ya tienes en otro archivo y ver si tienes líos ahí; luego ya es cuestión de modificar el input y entregárselo al output...

Comment: @Alfabravo el contenido que no necesito son las cabeceras HTTP que aparece en el fragmento de codigo de salida.... El problema es que no se como podría empezar a recorrer el CSV desde otra posición. quizas desde la fila 10 por ejemplo y que vaya hacia abajo, entonces podría generar otro CSV. pero también necesito eliminar columnas que no necesito y no se hacerlo

Comment: La pregunta, ya puedes verlo, es bien amplia. Lo primero es que revises en el CSVreader su documentación para que veas cómo leer las filas que quieres. Lo segundo, comienza recorriéndolo todo y lo guardas. De último, filtra los datos. PD. No entiendo la etiqueta PHP

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por tu respuesta. Voy a detallar un poco más mi pregunta y añadiré un código actual que he conseguido más o menos hacer lo que quiero, pero no está bien al 100%